# Facebook Business Extension throws an error when adding a variant of configurable product

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, facebook

FacebookBusiness extension was installed without problems a few days ago but no I have tried adding a different colour to my configurable product and keep getting this error.

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/app/code/Facebook/BusinessExtension/Model/Feed/ProductFeed.php on line 107

```
            'main_image' => $this->_fbeHelper->getBaseUrlMedia() . 'catalog/product' . $mainImage,
```

this is a longer snippet

```
private function getProductImages(Product $product)
{
    $mainImage = $product->getImage();
    $additionalImages = [];

    foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $img) {
        if ($img['file'] === $mainImage) continue;
    }
    return [
        'main_image' => $this->_fbeHelper->getBaseUrlMedia() . 'catalog/product' . $mainImage,
        'additional_images' => array_slice($additionalImages, 0, 10)
    ];
}
```

**Magento 2.3.6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same Problem with the Facebook Business Extension 1.2.0. Upgrading it to 1.2.3 (download from https://www.facebook.com/business/help/532749253576163) solved it for me.

Comment: yes, same here, the latest version from FB doesn't throw an error)